# TestNG unable to instantiate class after upgrade to JDK 11

Tags: testng, java-11, powermock

In Eclipse test cases which worked with Oracle JDK 8 now failing after JDK upgrade to Oracle JDK 11. Console shows following exception

> org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class com.aa.bb.test.SomeTest

pom.xml has following related dependencies

> testng: 6.8,  powermock-core: 1.7.3,  powermock-api-mockito2: 1.7.3,  powermock-module-testng: 1.7.3,

I suspected it may be due to some dependencies' version incompatibility so tried updating testng to 7.x.x and powermock dependencies to 2.x.x but it resulted in the same error.

What am I missing here?

```
stack trace below

org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.aa.bb.test.SomeTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:27)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:63)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:561)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1260)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
```

Comment: Can you show full stack trace?

Comment: @AlexeyR. stack trace added in question.